# C# - StreamReader incompatible with Content-Length?

Tags: c#, utf-8, streamreader, content-length

I receive a JSON from an http stream

I rely on the Content-Length header to read the body, but the StreamReaders reads extra characters

is it possible to use the Content-Length value of the header as-is while using a StreamReader ?

**with this function, there are extra characters after the JSON which makes it unparsable**

```
string ReceiveJSON(StreamReader input, int msgSize)
{
    var buffer = new char[msgSize];
    int offset = 0;
    var toRead = msgSize;
    while (toRead > 0)
    {
        var charsRead = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, toRead);
        offset += charsRead;
        toRead -= charsRead;
    }
    return new string(buffer, 0, msgSize);
}
```

but **this function does not add extra characters after the JSON**

```
void ReceiveJSON(Stream input, int msgSize)
{
    var buffer = new byte[msgSize];
    int offset = 0;
    while(msgSize > 0)
    {
        var readSize = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, msgSize);
        offset += readSize;
        msgSize -= readSize;
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}
```

I am requested to use the StreamReader, but

**how can I solve the first function so it reads the right amount of bytes ?**

thanks for your help

Comment: What happens if you also use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)` in the first snippet?

Comment: Length in bytes is not the same as length in characters.

Comment: Depending on the type of stream you have, you can try using `stream.SetLength(msgSize)` before you create the StreamReader

Comment: @Klaus one use chars, the other one bytes so I cannot use Encoding.UTF8.GetString. AFAIK StreamReader deals with UTF8 directly, hence my question